# How to query Internet Explorer version so it works for IE10 also?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, registry, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

My old code in C++ desktop application detected IE version by querying the value in

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version
```

registry key. This works for Internet Explorer 9 and below but doesn't work for Internet Explorer 10 (still returns 9).

What is the correct way to find out the IE version including IE 10 and higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another value called `svcVersion`, which I believe is only for IE10. This will correctly say `10.0.x`.